# How to enter absence of a break (linking symbol IPA) in LaTeX (Overleaf)?

Tags: symbols, languages, letters, tipa, english

[image]
the symbol of IPA International Phonetic Alphabet

Comment: Are you using pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex? Also I assume you're using tipa package?

Answer (score 3):

It's in the manual of `tipa` package...

[image: tipa manual]

For example:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}

1\textbottomtiebar 2

1\textbottomtiebar\ 2

1\textipa{\t*{}}2

1‿2


\end{document}
```

Compiled with xelatex:

[image: output]

in the last example, the Unicode character is entered directly. (although that one doesn't immediately work with pdflatex)

Comment: For LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you would be better off using `tipauni`. That maps the `tipa` commands to Unicode characters, rather than using obsolete 8-bit fonts.

Comment: One advantage is that the output can be copied, pasted and searched for. It might also match the font better.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use `tipauni` in the modern toolchain when you can, and the legacy 8-bit fonts from `tipa` when you’re forced to.  The advantages include being able to copy, paste and search the PDF.

Any time you’re using Unicode symbols that some of your fonts don’t have, I strongly recommend you use `\tracinglostchars=3` to make it an error when you try to display a glyph from a font that does not have it. The default behavior is to fail quietly, burying a warning in the middle of a `.log` file.

Here is a sample using `tipauni` with the font Charis SIL.  (The SIL fonts were created by linguists and usually have excellent support for IPA.  The default, New Computer Modern, will work for most purposes.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3

\usepackage[documentfont=CharisSIL]{tipauni}

\begin{document}

\textbottomtiebar{12}

1\textbottomtiebar\ 2

1\textipa{\t*{}}2

1‿2

\end{document}
```

[image: Charis SIL sample]